# What are .data and .text in x86?

Tags: x86

1

```
.data
value: .long 0x69
.text
#...
```

2

```
.text
value: .long 0x69
#...
```

I'm a student learning x86 and I noticed that `value` can't be modified if it's under `.text`. I've been trying to read why, but I couldn't find it. Can someone lead me to where I can read about it or explain it briefly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.text` section is the region of an executable where the actual executable instructions lie, and the `.data` section is the region of an executable where the non-stack based variables and constants lie. The reason why you can't modify values in the `.text` section is because of a security feature called [W^X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX)(aka PaX, Exec Shield, DEP, etc), which is enabled on most of the modern operating systems, where the OS disallows region of the memory unwritable while they are being executed. It's there to help alleviate arbitrary code injections.

Comment: I always thought that memory protection is done by MMU and not the OS. For example, there is no protection say, on Nios II CPUs, since there is no MMU, no matter how hard OS can try. Isn't it?

Comment: I would put it this way: OS is the one that makes policies whereas the components that support it (e.g. MMU) are the ones who actually enforce them.